# How to render HTML string with Vue syntax coming from Axios GET?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, symfony, vuejs3

I have a `Symfony 5` and `Vue 3` app, a Symfony controller is creating a form and providing its HTML through a JSON response, which is gibing me the form HTML as a string like so

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $view = $this->renderView('vue/regForm.html.twig',[
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

    return new JsonResponse([
        'form' => $view,
    ]);
}
```

In my Register.vue file, I have

```
<template>
    <h1>Selected Plan</h1>
    <div id="post-form-holder" ref="form" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        async mounted() {
            let { data } = await this.$http.get("/register/get/" + this.$route.params.plan);
            this.$refs.form.innerHTML = data.form
        },
    };
</script>
```

This is all working and the form is output onto the page successfully etc. My problem comes when I add some Vue syntax to the form in regForm.html.twig file, (eg. `v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': hasError }"`) the Vue syntax obviously does get rendered when using innderHTML.

Basically, how can I get the Vue syntax within `regform.html.twig` to render when the form is placed on the page in Vue 3.

Comment: Use `v-html` https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-html

Comment: `v-html` will not help here as it is designed to render pure HTML, not partial Vue templates...

Answer (score 0):

There is the `v-html` directive.
Check this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML